# How to define unit matrix?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

We have unit vector,w.r.t $2$-norm. I mean $$e_v = \frac{v}{\|v\|_2},$$ so $\|e_v\|_2=1$.

Do we have unit matrix w.r.t different matrix norm?

For example, unit matrix w.r.t Frobenius norm, $\|X\|_F = (\text{tr }(X^TX))^{1/2}$, so $$e_X = \frac{X}{\|X\|_F}.$$

Can we define the unit matrix in this way?  Does it have the same properties as unit vector?

Any suggestions or reference?   Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you heard about unitary matrices? They would be the natural starting point for something like this in my mind.

Comment: @QC_QAOA Yes! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general, whenever you have a [normed vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) $(V,\|\|)$ and a nonzero vector $v\in V$, you can always define a vector "with unit length" by
$$
w=\frac{v}{\|v\|}
$$